# Can't scrape particular items from some elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

What to do when there is no container or group to select to parse the required items (which are common in each group) looping through it? I'm willing to parse the text, date and author from the pasted elements. The three results I am after do not belong to any particular group or container so I can't find the right way to get them creating a loop.

Here are the elements:

```
html = '''
<div class="view-content">            
  <p class="text-large experts-more-h">   
  <a href="/publications/commentary/we-have-no-idea-universal-preschool-actually-helps-kids">We Have No Idea if Universal Preschool Actually Helps Kids</a>
  </p>
  <p class="text-sans">    
  By David J. Armor. Washington Post. <span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2014-10-21T09:34:00-04:00">October 21, 2014</span>.
  </p>        
  <p class="text-large experts-more-h">   
  <a href="/publications/commentary/last-parent-resistance-collective-standardized-tests">At Last, Parent Resistance to Collective Standardized Tests</a>
  </p>
  <p class="text-sans">    
  By Nat Hentoff. Cato.org. <span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2014-01-15T09:57:00-05:00">January 15, 2014</span>.
  </p>  
  <p class="text-sans">    
  By Darcy Ann Olsen and Eric Olsen. Cato.org. <span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="1999-04-15T00:00:00-04:00">April 15, 1999</span>.
  </p>       
  <p class="text-large experts-more-h">   
  <a href="/publications/commentary/day-care-parents-versus-professional-advocates-0">Day Care: Parents versus Professional Advocates</a>
  </p>
  <p class="text-sans">   
  By Darcy Ann Olsen. Cato.org. <span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="1998-06-01T00:00:00-04:00">June 1, 1998</span>.
  </p>  
</div>
'''
```

If you run my script, you can see that the scraped results is only the first one:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

tree = fromstring(html)
post= tree.cssselect(".text-large a")[0].text
date = tree.cssselect(".date-display-single")[0].text
author = tree.cssselect(".text-sans")[0].text.strip()
print(post+'\n', date+'\n', author)
```

Result:

```
We Have No Idea if Universal Preschool Actually Helps Kids
 October 21, 2014
 By David J. Armor. Washington Post.
```

If you run this one, you will see that this script is able to parse all the results I'm after:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

tree = fromstring(html)
count = tree.cssselect(".text-large a")

for item in range(len(count)):
    post= tree.cssselect(".text-large a")[item].text
    date = tree.cssselect(".date-display-single")[item].text
    author = tree.cssselect(".text-sans")[item].text.strip()
    print(post+'\n', date+'\n', author)
```

Results:

```
We Have No Idea if Universal Preschool Actually Helps Kids
 October 21, 2014
 By David J. Armor. Washington Post.
At Last, Parent Resistance to Collective Standardized Tests
 January 15, 2014
 By Nat Hentoff. Cato.org.
Day Care: Parents versus Professional Advocates
 April 15, 1999
 By Darcy Ann Olsen and Eric Olsen. Cato.org.
```

However, what i did with my second script is not at all pythonic and it will give wrong results if any data is missing. So, how to select a group or container, loop through it and parse all of them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you search for CSS solution only or XPath is also acceptable?

Comment: @ sir Andersson, It's always a great pleasure to have you in my thread. Be it xpath or css selector - most of these I've learnt from you. Any solution will do from your end. Btw, I can see that css selector has some limitations but I'm very much fond of it..

Comment: You said that *it will give wrong results if any data is missing*... Do you mean that HTML source could be different? Can you share HTML for this case also?

Comment: No no not like that. I meant, if any date or author name is none in some fields then there is a possibility to get the result messy. Whatever, there is nothing missing here and my second script is running ok but I'm not satisfied with my second script. I hope there is any better way to accomplish this. Thanks sir.

Comment: You can take it as an identical site where it is hard to make a container to get the "title" and "point" using loop. https://news.ycombinator.com/

Comment: Still not sure I correctly understood the issue.. What data you want to scrape from provided link? Do you want your code to be applicable both to HTML from question body and to HTML source from provided link?

Comment: I meant that if you want to get title and point from the linked site, you need to use following-sibling there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of text nodes (`post`, `date`, `author`) is missing, `tree.cssselect(selector)[index].text` should return you a `NoneType` object which you cannot handle as a string. To avoid this you can implement

```
post= tree.cssselect(".text-large a")[item].text or " "
```

You can also try below `XPath` solution:

```
container = tree.cssselect(".text-large")

for item in container:
    post = item.xpath('./a')[0].text or " "
    date = item.xpath('./following-sibling::p/span[@class="date-display-single"]')[0].text or " "
    author = item.xpath('./following-sibling::p[@class="text-sans"]')[0].text.strip() or " "
    print(post+'\n', date+'\n', author)
```

Comment: That means "[item].text or " "" can be used as well. This is new to me.

Comment: This is some kind of short version of  ternary conditional operator: `[item].text if [item].text else " "`

Comment: This is great to know. I felt it erroneous that is why I avoided it but next time i will give it a try. Thanks.